# .Net 6 generate *.resx or convert *.resources to *.resx

Tags: .net, linux, resources, porting, resx

I have to port some app from .NET Framework to .NET6. The app generates Localization.resx using ResXResourceWriter, but in .NET6 it not supported anymore. As I understood Microsoft moved to another format and they added System.Resources.ResourceWriter. This class generates *.resources (binary) but it not suitable because another service use .resx.

I found out resgen.exe - this console tool allows converting resource types but it works only on Windows.

Is there any way to generate *resx or convert *.resources to resx?

Also I found  but I would like to find couple other options for enterprise solutions.

Probably somebody meet such issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This class is available since .NET Core 3.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resxresourcewriter?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek, it isn't cross-platform, it has a dependency to Windows Desktop